# Apply style to ng2-pdf-viewer document in browser

Tags: css, angular, pdf-viewer

I'm trying to apply some basic styling to my rendered pdf. I'm using [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer#readme) to show my pdf in the browser:

```
<pdf-viewer src="https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf"></pdf-viewer>
```

Which generates the following DOM:

[image]

I would imagine the following css would do the trick, especially using `!important`:

```
.canvasWrapper {
    margin-top: 5px !important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why `!important` didn't do the trick but the following worked:

```
:host ::ng-deep .pdfViewer .page .canvasWrapper {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```